# how to create input fields for values in Photoshop scripting

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I'm working with Photoshop scripting and I have converted action to script which works fine.
I have defined the save as file name with a variables like this:

```
var path="~/desktop/Images/";
var start ="a";
```

and the saving path is set like this:

```
desc1.putPath(cTID('In  '), new File(path + start + "001"));
```

and the next save will be:

```
desc1.putPath(cTID('In  '), new File(path + start + "002"));
```

how do I make pop up box every time I run the script with the inputs of the path and start values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok i found it out. Thought ill put it here so that it might help others.

```
  var Path= Folder.selectDialog("Select folder to save");
  var Start =prompt("Layer Name","","Input Layer Name");

  desc1.putPath(cTID('In  '), new File(Path + "/" + Start + "001"));
```